# JavaScript appendChild text node doesn't break line

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

a JavaScript n00b here...
I'm generating some html code in javascript, that is going to be displayed as code via the [prism HTML markup plugin](http://prismjs.com/index.html). The code is dynamically added to a <pre> tag on a button click.

My javascript code is as below. It is the text in line 2, where I need a line break. I have tried /n but that doesn't work it just makes a space.

```
var startLabelTag = document.createTextNode("text goes here");
startLabelTag.nodeValue = "<label><strong>" + elementNameFinal + "</strong></label>LINEBREAK HERE<select id='dropdownmenu' class='Custom_" + fieldNameFinal + "' onchange='selectChanged('@field[" + fieldNameFinal + "]',this.value);'>";
document.getElementById("dropdown-code").appendChild(startLabelTag);
```

Below is the text string I'm trying to create, where a line break is made where the text LINEBREAK HERE is.

```
<label><strong>" + elementNameFinal + "</strong></label>LINEBREAK HERE<select id='dropdownmenu' class='Custom_" + fieldNameFinal + "' onchange='selectChanged('@field[" + fieldNameFinal + "]',this.value);'>
```

Comment: Would a normal HTML line break work here? <br/>

Comment: No because the HTML is shown as markup, so it would just be shown as "plain text"

Comment: Ah yes I see. Hmmm....

Comment: have you tried \r\n ?

Comment: Also only makes a space

Comment: Try wrapping the whole lot in <pre> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

By using `String.fromCharCode(10)` you can insert a line break and with the `pre` tag (or `div` having `white-space: pre-wrap`) the line break will be visible/shown.

```js
var elementNameFinal = "elementname", fieldNameFinal = "fieldname";

var startLabelTag = document.createTextNode("text goes here");
startLabelTag.nodeValue = "<label><strong>" + elementNameFinal + "</strong></label>" + String.fromCharCode(10) + "<select id='dropdownmenu' class='Custom_" + fieldNameFinal + "' onchange='selectChanged('@field[" + fieldNameFinal + "]',this.value);'>";

document.getElementById("dropdown-code").appendChild(startLabelTag);
```

```html
<pre id="dropdown-code"></pre>
```

*Side note*

You can of course use a `div` as well, having the CSS rule *Niet the Dark Absol* suggested.

```
<div id="dropdown-code"></div>

#dropdown-code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: pre-wrap` to the container's CSS.

After all, if you type a newline in your HTML source, do you get a blank line in the result? Nope. Not without making whitespace significant through CSS.